# Java openjpa-all 3.2.0 or latest with sqlite getting error to find 'user' column name

Tags: sqlite, openjpa

I have a web application project using **sqlite** latest version (3.40.1.0) and **openjpa-all** latest (3.2.2).

I created a dummy db using sqlite3 command with the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
user TEXT COLLATE NOCASE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,'test');
```

Using openjpa-all to recover data (select statement), got an error message from openjpa framework saying that USER0 column is not valid. Instead I am using the right column name 'user' and for some reason framework is switching the name of column to USER0.

Any clue how to resolve?

Here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-3.2.2-re5933d6 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: t0.USER0) {SELECT t0.id, t0.USER0 FROM test t0} [code=1, state=null]
FailedObject: SELECT a FROM Test a [java.lang.String]
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:5326)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:5286)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:134)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:115)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:67)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.SelectResultObjectProvider.handleCheckedException(SelectResultObjectProvider.java:162)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.rop.EagerResultList.<init>(EagerResultList.java:42)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.toResult(QueryImpl.java:1314)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:1061)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:911)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:842)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:601)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:297)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:314)
    at com.kyndryl.main.Testando.main(Testando.java:31)
Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: t0.USER0) {SELECT t0.id, t0.USER0 FROM test t0} [code=1, state=null]
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:219)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:199)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.access$000(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:58)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator$LoggingConnection.prepareStatement(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:252)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:138)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ConfiguringConnectionDecorator$ConfiguringConnection.prepareStatement(ConfiguringConnectionDecorator.java:144)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:138)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager$RefCountConnection.prepareStatement(JDBCStoreManager.java:1699)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:127)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLBuffer.prepareStatement(SQLBuffer.java:517)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLBuffer.prepareStatement(SQLBuffer.java:497)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.prepareStatement(SelectImpl.java:511)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.execute(SelectImpl.java:452)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.execute(SelectImpl.java:423)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion$UnionSelect.execute(LogicalUnion.java:477)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion.execute(LogicalUnion.java:259)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion.execute(LogicalUnion.java:248)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.SelectResultObjectProvider.open(SelectResultObjectProvider.java:95)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.rop.EagerResultList.<init>(EagerResultList.java:36)
    ... 8 more
NestedThrowables:
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: t0.USER0)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:1179)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:1190)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:1150)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare_utf8(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare(NativeDB.java:126)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.prepare(DB.java:264)
    at org.sqlite.core.CorePreparedStatement.<init>(CorePreparedStatement.java:46)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.<init>(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:31)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4PreparedStatement.<init>(JDBC4PreparedStatement.java:25)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC4Connection.java:34)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.prepareStatement(JDBC3Connection.java:226)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:140)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator$LoggingConnection.prepareStatement(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:249)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:138)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ConfiguringConnectionDecorator$ConfiguringConnection.prepareStatement(ConfiguringConnectionDecorator.java:144)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:138)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager$RefCountConnection.prepareStatement(JDBCStoreManager.java:1699)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:127)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLBuffer.prepareStatement(SQLBuffer.java:517)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLBuffer.prepareStatement(SQLBuffer.java:497)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.prepareStatement(SelectImpl.java:511)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.execute(SelectImpl.java:452)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.execute(SelectImpl.java:423)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion$UnionSelect.execute(LogicalUnion.java:477)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion.execute(LogicalUnion.java:259)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.LogicalUnion.execute(LogicalUnion.java:248)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.SelectResultObjectProvider.open(SelectResultObjectProvider.java:95)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.rop.EagerResultList.<init>(EagerResultList.java:36)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.toResult(QueryImpl.java:1314)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:1061)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:911)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:842)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:601)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:297)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:314)
    at com.kyndryl.main.Testando.main(Testando.java:31)
```

This is the following code I did to recover the data:

```
package com.company.entities;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "user", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    public Test() {
        super();
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Teste [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Much simple then I thought. Add double quotes in the column name. See column annotation of name attribute like below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "\"user\"", nullable = false)
    private String name;
```